# Can't convert raw SQL to sequelize

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I've been trying to convert this particular MariaDB SQL query to sequelzie, but I can't find in the docs anything related to JSON_SEARCH.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE JSON_SEARCH(attributes,'all','X') like '"$[%].value1"' and JSON_SEARCH(attributes,'all','Y') like '"$[%].value2"';
```

The attributes columns is a JSON (longtext) column. Contents have this pattern:

```
[
{value1:"X", value2:"Y" },
{value1:"a", value2:"b" },
{value1:"c", value2:"d" },
]
```

Maybe someone has implemented something simimlar, I would highly appreciate the help. Thank you

Comment: perobably isn't JSON_SEARCH isn't standard SQL.

Comment: Yes,but I think this can be written as a Sequelize.fn, but can't figure it out.

Comment: I would simplify to one JSON_SEARCH; and then did you see this `Post.findAll({
  where: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('char_length', sequelize.col('content')), 7)
});` here: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html

Comment: can you share what you tried?